# pulling whole records qualifying multiple values in the same column (relational division)

Tags: teradata

In a very simplified example, I want to pull FULL records of owners who BOTH drive a read car in London AND a white diesel. Not the records with blue cars, or cars from Kosovo or Kiev.

I came up with 2 incomplete solutions, but so far failed to get an accurate SQL that could address this.

**Incomplete solution #1**

```
select  
  -- * /* will not work */
  owner  
from cars 
where (color ='red' and city='London') or (color='white' and type='diesel')
group by owner
having count(distinct color)=2;
```

This only gives me the owners I'm looking for, but not the full record. ALSO this won't work with ranges or wildcards, if I define "red" as "light red" or "red" or "dark red", id est - where color like '%red%' or color='white'.

This looks gruffish, will likely work with wildcards, still - not pulling the full record.

```
select  
  owner  
from cars 
where (color ='red' and city='London') or (color='white' and type='diesel')
group by owner
having count(distinct 
  case when color like '%red%' then 1
       when color ='green' then 0
  end)=2;
```

**Incomplete solution #2**

```
select owner where color like '%red%' and city='London'
intersect 
select owner where color ='white' and type='diesel';
```

This is slick, would give me the correct list of owners even with wildcards, but **still** doesn't allow me to pull the full record, as it'll grab cars from Berlin, blue cars etc - if I select using "where owner in (...)" clause.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated, been walking around this for quite some time now.

Answer (score 2):

```
select      *  

from        cars 

where       (   color   = 'red'   
            and city    = 'london'
            )
        or  (   color   = 'white' 
            and type    = 'diesel'
            )   

qualify     min (color) over (partition by owner) <>
            max (color) over (partition by owner)
```

or

```
select      *  

from        cars 

where       (   color   = 'red'   
            and city    = 'london'
            )
        or  (   color   = 'white' 
            and type    = 'diesel'
            )   

qualify         max (case when color = 'red'   and city = 'london' then 1 else 0 end) 
                    over (partition by owner)
            +   max (case when color = 'white' and type = 'diesel' then 1 else 0 end) 
                    over (partition by owner)
            =   2
```

Comment: The second version pulls all records for that owner - including his blue cars and cars owned in Berlin... However, the first one pulled only 2 records as requested. I'll see if I can adjust your second query because then more than 2 conditions could be met if the query started getting additional filters...

Comment: I got a feeling that the last edit was a mistake... rolled back to the previous version

Comment: Yes, the where clause made the difference (v2). I even tried it with some twisted conditions (color='white' or type='diesel') and it still gets the record list correctly. Not an easy SQL to generate programmatically, but does the job.

Comment: See updated version of the 2nd option. Using the conditions "as is"

Comment: It is expensive when running in full production, but it does pull right. Looks like one of the solutions for relational division queries is a combination of a WHERE OR clause wrapped with quality.

Comment: What is expensive? The windows functions? It is the same window definition. It is going to be done in a single step.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. It was expensive (v2) w/out the where clause. With it (and correct results) runs as fast as the intersect I had in mind earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `QUALIFY` clause with a `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM cars 
WHERE (color ='red' and city='London') or (color='white' and type='diesel')    
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY owner) = 2
```

The initial set of records is filtered by the WHERE statement, so it makes a lot of sense. Then that QUALIFY runs on the results and makes a count of records for each `owner`. If that count is 2, then it allows the record through.

If you are unfamiliar with Window Funtions, then you might like to toss this one up in the results so you can see what numbers it's coming up with:

```
SELECT  cars.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY owner) as count_of_records_for_owner
FROM cars 
WHERE (color ='red' and city='London') or (color='white' and type='diesel')    
/*QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY owner) = 2*/
```

And you'll see the last field shows the total number of records for that particular owner. The Qualify statement just takes it a step further and filters on the results of that calculation.

Comment: First one will not work as exactly specified if you have two records of a red car in London (red diesel and a red gasoline), since it'll qualify as count(*)==2 despite not having a record of a white car. Checking further...